# How can I show & scroll particular bound of view for google map? other part of map we can't see and scroll

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I found a method for android called setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget. But could not find for ios. Has any one idea about it? I want to scroll into particular bound. User can't scroll out of the bound which is already defined

Comment: It's clearly stated in the docs for the Google Maps iOS SDK how to move the camera: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view (`moveCamera` or `animateToCameraPosition` on a `GMSMapView`)

Comment: Yes but I want to scroll into particular bound. User can't scroll out of the bound which is already defined.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. It's a property called `cameraTargetBounds` on `GMSMapView` which, again, is clearly identified in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view.html#af18afcf5b4eab9edf2b700734d2c7f07 The docs should always be your first stop for answering any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used cameraTargetBounds but not useful for me. Then I used

```
    func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didChangeCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition) {

    var latitude  = position.target.latitude;
    var longitude = position.target.longitude;

    if (position.target.latitude > bounds.northEast.latitude) {
        latitude = bounds.northEast.latitude;
    }

    if (position.target.latitude < bounds.southWest.latitude) {
        latitude = bounds.southWest.latitude;
    }

    if (position.target.longitude > bounds.northEast.longitude) {
        longitude = bounds.northEast.longitude;
    }

    if (position.target.longitude < bounds.southWest.longitude) {
        longitude = bounds.southWest.longitude;
    }

    if (latitude != position.target.latitude || longitude != position.target.longitude) {

        var l = CLLocationCoordinate2D();
        l.latitude  = latitude;
        l.longitude = longitude;

        mapView.animateToLocation(l);

    }
}
```

And it works.

Comment: Tried this solution but it introduces so much lag in my application that makes it unusable

Answer (score 2):

The iOS equivalent method is setCameraTargetBounds. You can use it as follows:

```
GMSCoordinateBounds *gmsBounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] 
    initWithCoordinate:bounds.northWest 
    coordinate:bounds.southEast];
[self.mapView setCameraTargetBounds:bounds];
```

Additionally, you may want to set a minimum zoom level, by doing this:

```
[self.mapView setMinZoom:15 maxZoom:23];
```

Comment: This is a proper way to do it. However, it seems that these bounds are set for camera center. This means that if you want that map outside these bounds should not be visible on screen at all - it won't work as with adjusting the zoom level it will be possible to see map outside the bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.8683,
                                      longitude: 151.2086,
                                      zoom: 16)
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.bounds, camera: camera)
```

[More](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/views)